# Select field for search action

Tags: symfony, search

I have my search field to search by category and article.

```
<div class="formsearch">
    <div class="title" style="float: left;">Search by category:</div>
    <form role="search" method="post" action="{{ path('search') }}">
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
            <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" style="width:70px;height:20px;"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

ACTION IN THE CONTROLLER:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data = $request->request->get('search');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Article a
         WHERE a.category LIKE :data'
    )->setParameter('data', $data);


    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('default/search.html.twig', array(
        'result' => $result
    ));
}
```

My question is: If I want to make the search field as a select field with all the category listed, so the user can select the category and it will star the search, how can i make this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it with some javascript code

```
$("#form_select_id").change(function(e){
   $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: But I wanted to do it without javascript :/

Comment: You are trying to  perform an action just after the user have selected a search category javascript is the only way because it's a client side code I don't see any other solution for it

Comment: Ok, so I can simply add that code you post to my page code and that's it?

Comment: But of course you will need to put it in $( document ).ready(function() { her }); and  set the id of the select field